# MassTransit republish message for another consumer when a consumer throws exception

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, masstransit

I am developing a micro-services system using MassTransit and RabbitMQ.
One service can publish jobs to many subscriber services.
One of subscribers will execute the job (Competing consumer).

If one subscriber consume a message, execute a job  and throw an exception, **is there any way to get the message re-delivered to the queue, so that other subscribers can consume that message.**

I use retry policy for the subscribers, but it only allows me to **re-consume the message inside the same subscriber, not consume by another subscriber.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can schedule redelivery of the message:

http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/redeliver.html

You need to have a message scheduler, or use the delayed exchange in RabbitMQ. Typically retrying immediately is discouraged, but you can set the redelivery timer to anything you want.

Comment: Do I need to do any additional setup for Quartz? I used `cfg.UseMessageScheduler(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/quartz"));` and use Redeliver() method in my code but it does not work. No message is re-delivered.

Comment: You have to run the quartz scheduler on a node. Look in the same docs for how to host it.

Comment: I could not find out that docs. Do you have any example for it?

Comment: I have a scheduling sample https://github.com/alexeyzimarev/Demo.MassTransit.Scheduling. It has a link to the MT.Quartz.Host, which you can just configure and run. Schedule persistence is defined in the app.config.

Comment: This page http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/scheduling/in-memory.html described how to host the Quartz endpoint in-process without persistence.